# How to manage concurrency in client JS?

Tags: javascript, async-await, concurrency, promise

I faced some issues regarding concurrency issue in client side JS. There are two lines of code which sends request using axios. But the following code is run before the callback function for axios request is completed.

Any way to solve this concurrency problem? As far as I know async/await is only used in backend JS like Node.JS

var declaration:

```
var chartGroundTank = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-ground-tank'));
var chartElevatedTank = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-elevated-tank'));

var optionChartGroundTank = {
    series: {
        type: 'liquidFill',
        data: [{
            name: '',
            value: 0,
            // waveAnimation: false,
            amplitude: '4%',
            itemStyle: {
                color: '',
            },
        }]
    }
};

var optionChartElevatedTank = {
    series: {
        type: 'liquidFill',
        data: [{
            name: "",
            value: 0,
            itemStyle: {
                color: ''
            },
            // waveAnimation: false,
            amplitude: '4%',
        }]
    }
};
```

function call:

```
 axios
    .get("/api/v1/firstAPI")
    .then(function (response) {
      const groundTankData = response.data.sensor1;
      const elevatedTankData = response.data.sensor2;
      setWaterTankColor(groundTankData, optionChartGroundTank, 'gnd'); // the values are 
      setWaterTankColor(elevatedTankData, optionChartElevatedTank, 'elv'); // set slower
      chartGroundTank.setOption(optionChartGroundTank); // this two lines
      chartElevatedTank.setOption(optionChartElevatedTank); // will run earlier
....
)};
```

function definition:

```
function setWaterTankColor(waterLevel, tankType) {
    axios.get("/api/v1/metrics/getData", {
        ...config,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            var { sensor1Info1, sensor1Info2, sensor2Info1, sensor2Info2 } = response.data;
            if (tankType == 'gnd') {
                var color = waterLevel < sensor1Info1 / 100 || waterLevel > sensor1Info2 / 100 ? optionChartGroundTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["red"] : optionChartGroundTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["#2f529a"];
            }
            else {
                var color = waterLevel < sensor2Info1 / 100 || waterLevel > sensor2Info2 / 100 ? optionChartElevatedTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["red"] : optionChartElevatedTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["#2f529a"];
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the promise, you have in `setWaterTankColor`, then you can set the option after the callback completed.

```
function setWaterTankColor(waterLevel, tankType) {
    return axios.get("/api/v1/metrics/getData", {
        ...config,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            var { sensor1Info1, sensor1Info2, sensor2Info1, sensor2Info2 } = response.data;
            if (tankType == 'gnd') {
                var color = waterLevel < sensor1Info1 / 100 || waterLevel > sensor1Info2 / 100 ? optionChartGroundTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["red"] : optionChartGroundTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["#2f529a"];
            }
            else {
                var color = waterLevel < sensor2Info1 / 100 || waterLevel > sensor2Info2 / 100 ? optionChartElevatedTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["red"] : optionChartElevatedTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["#2f529a"];
            }
        });
}
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
 axios
    .get("/api/v1/firstAPI")
    .then(function (response) {
      const groundTankData = response.data.sensor1;
      const elevatedTankData = response.data.sensor2;
      setWaterTankColor(groundTankData, optionChartGroundTank, 'gnd').then(function() { chartGroundTank.setOption(optionChartGroundTank); });
      setWaterTankColor(elevatedTankData, optionChartElevatedTank, 'elv').then(function() { chartElevatedTank.setOption(optionChartElevatedTank); });
....
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

That two lines of codes run earlier because they are sync functions.
In order to make them run later, you can await for the the function `setWaterTankColor` first.
You can use async/await in your case. I also add `trycatch` to catch error from API call.

```js
(async function run() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("/api/v1/firstAPI");
    const groundTankData = response.data.sensor1;
    const elevatedTankData = response.data.sensor2;
    await setWaterTankColor(groundTankData, optionChartGroundTank, "gnd");
    await setWaterTankColor(elevatedTankData, optionChartElevatedTank, "elv");
    chartGroundTank.setOption(optionChartGroundTank);
    chartElevatedTank.setOption(optionChartElevatedTank);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();

async function setWaterTankColor(waterLevel, tankType) {
  try {
    const response = axios.get("/api/v1/metrics/getData", {
      ...config,
    });

    const { sensor1Info1, sensor1Info2, sensor2Info1, sensor2Info2 } =
      response.data;

    if (tankType == "gnd") {
      var color =
        waterLevel < sensor1Info1 / 100 || waterLevel > sensor1Info2 / 100
          ? (optionChartGroundTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["red"])
          : (optionChartGroundTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = [
              "#2f529a",
            ]);
    } else {
      var color =
        waterLevel < sensor2Info1 / 100 || waterLevel > sensor2Info2 / 100
          ? (optionChartElevatedTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = ["red"])
          : (optionChartElevatedTank.series.data[0].itemStyle.color = [
              "#2f529a",
            ]);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```